# How do i save multiple strings and not overwrite while writing to a plist file in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using a "facts.plist" to display a fact(string) after pressing a button, i have a button there that writes that string to a **"favourites.txt"** file and there i can use it for future use.

Here is the code for that:

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFavorites.txt"];
                      //documentsDirectory];

[self.displayJoke.text writeToFile:fileName
          atomically:NO
            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
               error:nil];
NSError *error;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fileName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

But every time I tap that button the previous string gets overwritten with the new string. How do i create a dictionary or Array to prevent this?

Comment: By creating a dictionary or Array.

Comment: How do i create a dictionary from it ? I'm using the self.displayJoke.text to display a string. If i press the"tap for new Joke" button it gets updated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> every time i tap that button the previous string gets overwritten with the new string

It doesn't "get overwritten". *You* are overwriting it:

```
[self.displayJoke.text writeToFile:fileName
      atomically:NO
        encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
           error:nil];
```

That line *replaces* the file *fileName* with a new file. If that's not what you want to do, then *don't do that*. If you want to include the existing contents of the file, it's up to you to read the file first and include that in what you write. (Alternatively, you could look into NSFileHandle, which allows you to append to a file.)